# Signed .mpkg file in Mac OS X 10.9.5 appears unsigned when installing in Mac OS X 10.10.1

Tags: macos, sign, mpkg

I have an myFile.mpkg file and signed it in Mac OS X 10.9.5 using the command line utility productsign and the following command:

```
productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: MyDeveloperInstallerId" myFile.mpkg 
mySignedFile.mpkg
```

The output when I ran the command is the following:

```
productsign: preparing "myFile.mpkg" for signing...
productsign: Using timestamp authority for signature
productsign: Wrote signed product archive to mySignedFile.mpkg
```

Then in order to verify that my file is signed I ran the command:

```
pkgutil --check-signature mySignedFile.mpkg
```

and the output was:

```
Package "mySignedFile.mpkg":
Status: signed by a certificate trusted by Mac OS X
Certificate Chain: etc...
```

Nevertheless when I tried to install my signed file to a Mac OS X 10.10.1 the following message appeared:

```
 mySignedFile.mpkg can't be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be 
 confirmed
```

Any idea why is this happening? Is there anything wrong in the signing process?

[UPDATE]

Found this [post](http://macinstallers.blogspot.gr/2014_08_01_archive.html)

and run the following command:

```
spctl -a -t exec -vv mySignedFile.mpkg
```

the output was:

```
mySignedFile.mpkg: rejected
source=obsolete resource envelope
```

which means that my package will be rejected by Gatekeeper on 10.9.5 (OSX Mavericks) /10.10 (OSX Yosemite) or above.

I also checked the version of the signature and found something strange:

```
codesign -dvvv mySignedFile.mpkg

Executable=mySignedFile.mpkg/Contents/distribution.dist
Identifier=mySignedFile
Format=installer package bundle
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=183 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Signature size=7589
Authority=Developer ID Application: My Company
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=Jan 14, 2015, 13:08:13 pm
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=XXXXXXXXX
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=4 files=2
Internal requirements count=1 size=200
```

Info.plist instead of having entries = a number equals to not bound.